# Custom weighted loss in cntk

Tags: python, cntk, loss

I like to calculate weighted error below:

```
def calc_err(pred, targets, weights) :
    nClass = np.size(pred, axis=0) 

    Is = [1.0 for i in range(nClass)]
    nonTargets = C.minus(Is, targets)
    wrongPred = C.minus(Is, pred)
    wColumn = C.times(targets, weights)
    wTarget = C.element_times(wColumn, targets)
    wNonTarget = C.element_times(wColumn, nonTargets)
    c1 = C.negate(C.reduce_sum(C.element_times(wTarget, C.log(pred)), axis = -1))
    c2 = C.negate(C.reduce_sum(C.element_times(wNonTarget, C.log(wrongPred)), axis = -1))
    ce = c1 + c2

    return ce.eval()
```

where pred is prediction probabilities, targets is expected one-hot array, and weights is 2D array.  I've created a corresponding custom loss below:

```
def WeightedCrossEntropy(z, targets):
    pred = C.softmax(z)
    nClass = np.size(pred, axis=0) 
    Is = [1 for i in range(nClass)]

    nonTargets = C.minus(Is, targets)
    wrongPred = C.minus(Is, pred)
    wColumn = C.times(targets, weights)
    wTarget = C.element_times(wColumn, targets)
    wNonTarget = C.element_times(wColumn, nonTargets)
    c1 = C.negate(C.reduce_sum(C.element_times(wTarget, C.log(pred)), axis=-1))
    c2 = C.negate(C.reduce_sum(C.element_times(wNonTarget, C.log(wrongPred)), axis=-1))
    ce = c1 + c2

    return ce
```

When I tried to train, I have noticed that while custom loss is indeed decreasing, but the test error from calc_err(pred, targets, weights) only decrease one or two epochs or not at all.  Is my WeightedCrossEntropy(z, targets) ok or what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Is the weights a constant or parameter? Please make sure these two function take the same inputs, parameters and constants.

Comment: The weights is pre-calculated as above. How do I verify these two function take the same inputs, parameters and constants?  I have revised code as  def WeightedCrossEntropy(z, targets):
    return calc_err(z, targets, weights)  so both test and loss function call calc_err, but still get the same results.  Please advise.  Thanks!

Comment: If the inputs are the same, difference between training data and test data may come from [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting). You should verify if calc_err outputs the same metric for training data as in training first, and if so it's a typical overfitting issue. There are several ways to address overfitting, including but not limited to adding dropout in model, use L1/L2 regularization in learner, etc.

Comment: You are correct, KeD. It seems indeed caused by overfitting.  I have increased L2 regularization from 0.0001 to 1.0, the test error will keep decrease up to 10 epochs.  I've tried with several other values, but all under 10 epochs.  We are using ResNet 20 layers and have 14000 samples with 64x64x3 inputs, what else can we do to reduce overfitting?

Comment: Please check out [this slide](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~guerzhoy/321/lec/W05/overfitting_prevent.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

The below is how weights are pre-calculated:

```
def ColBasedCustomWeight(nClass) :
    ratio = 1.0
    pfSum = [0] * nClass
    pWs = [[0 for x in range(nClass)] for y in range(nClass)]
    for j in range(nClass):
        for i in range(nClass):
            n = i - j
            if n > 0: 
                # false negative if j = 0
                pWs[j][i] = math.pow(1.5,ratio*n) if j == 0 else math.pow(1.2,ratio*n) 
            elif n < 0:
                # false positive if i = 0
                pWs[j][i] = math.pow(1.5, -ratio*n) if i == 0 else math.pow(1.2, -ratio*n)
            else: 
                pWs[j][i] = 1.0
            pfSum[i] += pWs[j][i]

    #normalize the weights to nClass
    for  j in range(nClass):
        for i in range(nClass):
            pWs[j][i] *= nClass / pfSum[i]

    return pWs
```

Any problems with the weight definition or calculation?